# Matplotlib with fig.text cropped

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code I need to make a common xlabel and common ylabel. For that, i used the figure.text() function, but the text is always cropped, no matter what I try (tight_layout, constrained_layout,etc.). The common xlabel and ylabel **have to have 2 lines**, and I imagine my difficulty arises from that:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axs[0, 0].scatter(dfA['old']*10, dfA['fin']*10)
axs[0, 0].set_title('A')
axs[0, 1].scatter(dfB['old']*10, dfB['fin']*10)
axs[0, 1].set_title('B')
axs[1, 0].scatter(dfC['old']*10, dfC['fin']*10)
axs[1, 0].set_title('C')
axs[1, 1].scatter(dfD['old']*10, dfD['fin']*10)
axs[1, 1].set_title('D')

fig.text(0.5, -0.02, 'metric' + '\n(before testing)', ha='center', clip_on=False)
fig.text(-0.005, 0.5, 'metric' + '\n(after testing)', ha='center',
         va='center', rotation='vertical', clip_on=False)
plt.tight_layout()
```

As you can see, in the final plot (1st plot with tight_layout() and the 2nd plot without tight_layout, the text appears cropped)
[image]
[image]

I also tried the following combinations of tight_layout() and subplots_adjust():

```
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)
```

[image]

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)
```

[image]

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You are using `fig.text` which default uses figure coordinates.  Values outside the range 0-1 are outside the figure.   You can change the x and y coordinates to place the text at a desired position, avoiding negative values.  You'll also need `subplots_adjust` without `tight_layout` to create enough open space. See [the transforms tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-advanced-transforms-tutorial-py) for additional info.

Comment: The main issue lies in another problem, as I can see the labels in the case where I don't want to "center" align the y_label. But if I align it (with ha='center' and va='center'), then the 1st line disappears from the plot

Comment: Yes, you need to move the text such that when centered nothing falls outside the figure (the figure is the complete surrounding plot which includes the subplots). The figure is fixed between 0 and 1.  For example `fig.text(0.5, 0.07, ...)` instead of `fig.text(0.5, -0.02, ...)`; this depends on the fontsize, the font used and on the size of the figure.

Comment: 3.4 and the development version of matplotlib now have supxlabel and supylabel for this exact case: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-figure-title-py

Answer (score 0):

(Leave the answer here if anyone has the same issue)

Following the comments of @JohanC, I changed the parameters of fig.text and used subplots_adjust:

```
fig.text(0.5, 0.02, 'metric' + '\n(before testing)', ha='center', clip_on=False)
fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'metric' + '\n(after testing)', ha='center',
         va='center', rotation='vertical', clip_on=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.12, bottom=0.12)
```

and the text was finally ok.